# Is it possible to duplicate projection on Windows 10 while not specifiying windows on the output?

Tags: windows, windows-10, projector

Is it possible to duplicate project on Windows 10 while not including a specific window on the output/only including specific windows on the output? For example, having a word document displayed on the projector and on the main display the word document as well as a web browser window over the top that is not visible in the projection.

Alternatively, perhaps its possible to have a window that is on both the primary and secondary display when the projection mode is extend.

Answer (score 0):

Windows itself only supports for multi-monitors the modes of Extended
or Mirrored, so you will need a third-party product for that.

The product
[Actual Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/)
($24.95 with trial) seems to fit your requirements and enable to mirror
a window or screen area to another monitor.

For a description of its usage see the article
[How to Mirror any Window to a Desired Display on Dual Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/articles/detail.php?ID=1382).